# Android studio fatal error : JUnit and Studio.Core exceptions when opening old files

Tags: android-studio

Yesterday I tried to open 2015-16 project in my latest version of android studio and make some changes . Now i am getting this IDE Fatal Error: 
 `Exception in JUnit and Exception in Studio.Core`

Also some of my projects files got corrupt.

It's there a way to work around this exceptions without re-installing Android Studio? What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find my own Solution .

Here is what you Need to do .

Close Android Studio

Go to C:\Users\UserName.android and rename the build-cache folder to build-cache.bak

Go to C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio3.2\system and rename these folders

caches to caches.bak

compile-server to compile-server.bak

compiler to compiler.bak

conversion to conversion.bak

external_build_system to external_build_system.bak

frameworks to frameworks.bak

gradle to gradle.bak

resource_folder_cache to resource_folder_cache.bak

Open the Android Studio and open your project again.